# Website backups on Amazon s3

Tags: amazon-s3, backup, debian, lamp

**EDIT:** I have completely changed the question.

I want to use Amazon S3 for my backups and I am looking for a debian lenny software (or a php script) that could allow me to achieve what I need. It is a flash games website:

1. Upload all files and subdirectories from the specified directories, but only uploading the files that were added/changed (overwrites old files on S3).
2. Perform a database dump and upload it to S3, keeping only 7 previous dumps.
3. Lightweight and easy to use
4. It has to be possible to run it as a cron job
5. Should work on Debian Lenny

Anything that matches all these specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP script [Website 2 Backup](http://website2backup.com) does exactly what you want :

1. Backup to Amazon S3
2. Incremental backup of files, only new and modified files are backuped, deleted files are listed.
3. Backup of the database, with auto clean of old archives
4. Clean and easy to setup ajax administration
5. It runs with the cron job

And it does more, data encrypted on serveur, data recovery with few clicks....

Comment: Thanks, very nice. Since then I have written my own script and switched servers, but a great answer nonetheless.

Answer (score 4):

[Automating backups with Amazon S3 on Linux](http://shapeshed.com/journal/automating_backups_with_amazon_s3_on_linux/).

You should be able to tweak the procedure this describes to meet your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

[Jungle Disk](https://www.jungledisk.com/) offers a server edition. It also gives you the choice to use Rackspace Cloud Files for backups instead of Amazon S3, which may be less expensive if you're going to be updating the backup often, as all data transfer to and from Cloud Files is free.